# Overflow:hidden in Chrome doesn't work

Tags: html, css

I've read all the suggestions about how to fix this, but my site is still allowing users to scroll horizontally no matter what I do. I've gotten the horizontal scrollbar to be hidden, but using arrow keys or the mouse wheel still lets users scroll.  I've tried to assign `overflow:hidden` on individual elements and on `html`.  Nothing seems to work.

#### HTML:

```
<body <?php body_class(); ?>>
<div id="page" class="hfeed site">
        <div id="shapes">
                <div id="design-shape"></div>   
                <div id="contact-shape"></div>  

       </div>   
</body>
```

#### CSS:

```
html {
font-size: 100%;
-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
position: relative;
vertical-align: baseline;
overflow-x: hidden;
}

#design-shape {
 background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #e98e82;
 position: absolute;
 transform:rotate(-45deg);
 -ms-transform:rotate(-45deg);
 -webkit-transform:rotate(-45deg);
 height: 1040px;
 top: 1200px;
 left:50%;
 width: 5000px;
 margin-left: -2500px;
 z-index: 6;
}

#contact-shape {
 background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #333333;
 position: absolute;
 transform:rotate(-45deg);
 -ms-transform:rotate(-45deg);
 -webkit-transform:rotate(-45deg);
 height: 800px;
 top: 1960px;
 left:50%;
 width: 5000px;
 margin-left: -2500px;
 z-index: 17;
 }
```

Comment: i dont see side scrolling.

Comment: You should post code here. Links will die over time. overflow:hidden works only for "block" elements. Maybe that's the problem?

Comment: Your body element has an explicit height...

Comment: At who element you try to add overflow:hidden?

Comment: You could try `html { overflow:hidden }` ...

Comment: Why would setting a height be a problem?

Comment: @rupps Aren't html and body block level elements?

Comment: `#shapes` must have a relative position in Chrome to get the overflow on this element working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## What's Going On

In Chrome, you can scroll sideways, which shows things that you don't want shown. This is despite not having a horizontal scrollbar.

The reason is that the shapes that extend over to the side are absolutely positioned, and their parent `#shapes` is not positioned relatively or absolutely, so it can't catch them. To fix this, we need to absolutely position `#shapes`, and set `position:relative` to `#shapes`'s parent, `#page` Add a few fiddly bits to ensure that everything is positioned correctly and we are good to go.

## Code

#### CSS:

```
#page {
    position:relative;
}

#shapes {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: thank you.  But I'm still able to side scroll in chrome.

Comment: When you say "a side scroll", do you mean a side scrollbar that scrolls the page vertically?

Comment: I actually don't see a scrollbar, but I'm able to scroll to the right and see part of the shapes that are not intended to be seen.

Comment: How do you scroll to the right? In Chrome and FF, when I add that, there are no scrollbars (vertical or horizontal), and scrolling my mousewheel does nothing. Edit: Nvm, I see.

Comment: I really appreciate your help. But now I can't scroll vertically.

Comment: I misunderstood the question from the beginning. I'll look into it again this evening. Sorry for the incorrect answer.

Comment: Figured out it. Editing now.

Answer (score 1):

There is two classes (shown below) that have a `width: 5000px;` and a `margin-left: -2500px`. Removing/changing that should fix the problem for you.

```
#design-shape {
 background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #e98e82;
 position: absolute;
 transform:rotate(-45deg);
 -ms-transform:rotate(-45deg);
 -webkit-transform:rotate(-45deg);
 height: 1040px;
 top: 1200px;
 left:50%;
 width: 5000px;
 margin-left: -2500px;
     z-index: 6;
 }

 #contact-shape {
 background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #333333;
 position: absolute;
 transform:rotate(-45deg);
 -ms-transform:rotate(-45deg);
 -webkit-transform:rotate(-45deg);
 height: 800px;
 top: 1960px;
 left:50%;
 width: 5000px;
 margin-left: -2500px;
 z-index: 17;
 }
```

EDIT:

Adding `position: relative;` to the shapes style should work.

```
#shapes {
overflow-x: hidden;
position: relative;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but it needs to be that wide.

Comment: That fixed the scroll issue but now the shape color is missing.